# Regex statement Improvement

Tags: regex

```
\$\([^\$^\(^\)]*\)
```

I'm using this statement to match any random string literal in bracket that is preceded by `$` character.

- `$(random_string)` -> `$(random_string)` should match.
- `$($($(cat)hat)bat))` -> only `$(cat)` should match (so that one can get the match placed most inner layer)
- `$()` Shouldn't match, but it does with the statement above.

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expresion `\$\([^$()]+\)` matches your specification.

It requires at least one non-`$()` character between parenthesis.

You can test it here: http://regex101.com/r/fL6sV3/1

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for light-speed answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your regex, replace `*` with `+`,

```
\$\([^\$^\(^\)]+\)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fL6sV3/2)

`*` means zero or more, so it matches the `$()` but `+` means one or more. Now `$()` shouldn't be matched because no characters are exists within paranthesis.